# Internal storage not being written

Tags: android

I'm trying to read from website url then write into device internal storage. Below are my code, the system output can print the line out but there is no file at internal storage. 
Suppose the abc.xml will appear at "/data/data/my-package/abc.xml" but there is nothing... 
Kindly help me on this problem.

```
    try {
        URL sourceUrl = new URL("mysite.php");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(sourceUrl.openStream()));

        String inputLine;

        OutputStream out = openFileOutput("abc.xml", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
                out.write(inputLine.getBytes());
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, e + "");
    }
```

Comment: And there's nothing in your Debug logs?

Comment: Have you added this permission in your manifest file  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>`

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple function that saves a user object to the internal storage. The code works and seems like same you wrote above except 1 difference. I also add 1 more catch statement which is the following

```
catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        Log.e(LOGTAG, e1.toString());
        return false;
}
```

I know it won't solve the problem but at least you may find out why it doesn't work if the program throws a FileNotFoundException